# Function to calculate total time divided by total time spent in r

Tags: r

I'm new to writing functions in R and was wondering if someone could help me with designing a function that would calculate the time(seconds) for each id when the count> 31 and divide it by the total time(seconds). I then need to add this fraction for all the ids

```
  id           timestamp      count
4466    12/1/14 19:57:00         47
4466    12/1/14 19:57:05         47
4466    12/1/14 19:57:10         47
4466    12/1/14 19:57:15         46
4466    12/1/14 19:57:20         45
1136    3/23/15 23:00:00         30
1136    3/23/15 23:00:05         32
1136    3/23/15 23:00:10         30
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you define the total time?

Comment: sounds like a typical data.table problem if I understand it correctly: Data[count>31,newvariable:=sum(timestamp)-timestamp,by=id]

Comment: Total time would be the number of seconds represented by each ID irrespective of the count

Comment: So for example: the total time for id 1136 is 10 seconds (23:00:00 to 23:00:10) ? And the count is assumed to be 32 from 23:00:05 to 23:00:10, so that = 5 seconds = 0.5 ?